# Extract the YEAR from a column set as a string with different formates for the dates in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQJAu.png)I need help getting this done, since I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm using Bigquery
I have this dataset shown in the screenshot, and I have been trying to **extract only the year** out of the column "Quality_Review___Dates_of_Review" but as shown in the red rectangle, the dates are not in a consistent format, also the column itself is formatted as a STRING!

I tried to CAST to date, datetime, extract, and even substring but everytime I get a different error because of the incosistency and the error in the date inputs itself

Comment: Are the only two options in date where you have the YYYY as the first four or last four bytes of the column? If so, then maybe a case expression could be used to extract the first four of the column if the first four are numeric, else grab last four.

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately I have some rows formatted as "2014-12-16T00:00:00.000" and other rows as "December 3-4, 2013"!

Comment: Which is exactly what I asked.... Are those the only formats? If so, then you check if the first four are numeric. You just need to find the right function for that part.

Comment: Oh! I got what you mean, but this would require me to combine the CASE with LIKE and EXTRACT as far as I understand! please do correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: See answer below and confirm if this provides a solution. This works as long as you have only 2 common formats.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong or not understanding it fully, but the output is giving me the year 2022 which I don't have in my dataset, I appreciate your patience and support very much though

Comment: Just to confirm, you're ignoring the CTE (ie, those first 4 rows) in the answer below, right? That CTE was simply providing some sample data to show you how it works. Just take the actual query itself, which starts on row 5.

Comment: I wasn't honestly, but I did now and it solved it, thanks a lot for your help I really appreciate that

Comment: Please consider marking the Accept answer flag if this is resolved. This will let others know the question has been resolved.

Comment: Will sure do, thanks again for walking me through this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, where you have only 2 formats (starting with a number or starting with a letter), then this works.

The case expression will check if the date starts with a letter. If so, then take the right last 4, else take the first 4 as the year.

```
with my_data as (
  select 1 as id, '2022-10-20T00:00:00.000' as qdate union all
  select 2, 'December 3-4, 2013'
)
select id, qdate, 
  case when regexp_contains(left(qdate,1), r'[a-zA-Z]') is true
   then right(qdate, 4) 
   else left(qdate,4) 
  end as q_year
from my_data

--Output--
id  qdate                    q_year
1   2022-10-20T00:00:00.000  2022
2   "December 3-4, 2013"     2013
```